# Delayed css when loading resources in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I just noticed that in chrome, if there are external resources to load like the background-image attribute, it delays the loading of the entire rest of the style sheet. Its really rather annoying since it causes the page to flicker even when loading just 4kB worth of images from localhost.

I could possibly work around it on any other page by placing image references at the end of my css but this particular page is too dependent on textures, it still looks bad.

This doesn't happen to images included directly in the loaded HTML like < img > tag or background images with inline CSS. Since I'm on asp.net, I could have the  css inlined into the response but this would come at the cost of bandwidth.

Is there any other way to get around this?

Comment: It depends where you are loading these images from. External sources have their own bandwidth. If their load is slow, so will yours. Unless, I misunderstood you. Why not keeping these images in am img folder and referencing locally?

Comment: @lotusms You are misunderstanding the problem, it isn't about loading speed but the fact that chrome freezes the CSS load to fetch the resources while FF or IE for example don't.

Comment: hmmm. I see. This is hard to figure out unless we can inspect the relevant code/page in the culprit environment(s)